# Keyboard keys are disappearing in iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am facing some issue regrading keyboard.

In debug it is working fine but on production keyboard keys are disappeared.
Not able to figure out this issue.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Got solution. Issue is from the pod. I removed it.

Comment: Got solution. Issue is from the pod(Gifu). I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a combination of a searchbar and the keyboard.
This is my code to solve the issue..

```
struct KeyboardAdaptive: ViewModifier {
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, keyboardHeight)
            .onReceive(Publishers.keyboardHeight) { self.keyboardHeight = $0 }
    }
}
struct CustomCorner : Shape {
    var corners: UIRectCorner
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
extension Publishers {
    // Declare a keyboard height publisher in the Publishers namespace. The publisher has two types – CGFloat and Never – which means that it emits values of type CGFloat and can never fail with an error.
    static var keyboardHeight: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        // Wrap the willShow and willHide notifications into publishers. Whenever the notification center broadcasts a willShow or willHide notification, the corresponding publisher will also emit the notification as its value. We also use the map operator since we are only interested in keyboard height.
        
        let willShow = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification)
            .map { $0.keyboardHeight }
        
        let willHide = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification)
            .map { _ in CGFloat(0) }
        
        // Combine multiple publishers into one by merging their emitted values.
        return MergeMany(willShow, willHide)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
extension Notification {
    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat {
        return (userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height ?? 0
    }
}
extension View {
    func keyboardAdaptive() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: KeyboardAdaptive())
    }
}
```

You just need to add the keyboardAdaptive modifier to your VStack, HStack, ZStack,..

```
VStack{
    ...
}.keyboardAdaptive().ignoresSafeArea()
```

Comment: thanks for your response and time.